# module object not callable using chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, module, selenium-chromedriver, typeerror

i'm trying to use python/selenium to just open chrome on a specific URL but i keep getting a TypeError:Module object not found error. i've tried looking up what i am doing wrong but nothing i have found helps.
Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 

PATH = "/home/matthew/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.chrome(PATH)

driver.get("google.com")
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matthew/Desktop/scraper.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = wb.chrome(PATH)
NameError: name 'wb' is not defined
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/home/matthew/Desktop/scraper.py"]
[dir: /home/matthew/Desktop]
[path: /home/matthew/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out i used .chrome instead of .Chrome that was what was throwing the error, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the `driver = webdriver.chrome(PATH)` to `driver = webdriver.Chrome(FULL/PTH)`

Answer (score -1):

try putting the chromedriver in the "C:\chromedrive"

Comment: what makes you sure that the OP is using Windows?